# Filter an array of objects by union types TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects like:

`array = [{name: 'something'}, {name: 'random'}, {name: 'bob'}]`

I have defined union type

`type NamesType = 'something' | 'bob'`

Is it possible to filter the array by the types? So the final result would be

`array = [{name: 'something'}, {name: 'bob'}]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
array = [{name: 'something'}, {name: 'random'}, {name: 'bob'}];
namesType = ['something','bob'];
filteredArray = array.filter(item => namesType.includes(item.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

One example could be using `Set` like this:

```js
const array = [{name: 'something'}, {name: 'random'}, {name: 'bob'}]
const namesType = new Set(['something','bob']);
const filteredArray = array.filter(item => namesType.has(item.name));
console.log(filteredArray)
```